# WebRtc C++ library peer stats report jitter

Tags: webrtc

In this library, does anybody know what the "jitter" value actually is for each report requested via this method defined in `peer_connection_interface`:

`virtual void GetStats(RTCStatsCollectorCallback* callback) = 0;`

Specifically, I am referring to this value received from webRtc in the report produced by the above callback:

```
  {
    "type": "inbound-rtp",
    "id": "RTCInboundRTPAudioStream_3482073958",
    "timestamp": 1613571893293000,
    "jitter": 0.004
  },
```

I cannot find a definition anywhere telling me whether - at any point in the call - this jitter value is the max jitter so far, the jitter of the last packet, or average jitter throughout the call ... or something else entirely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That value is the jitter from the RTCP Receiver Reports.

It is defined in [RFC3550](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3550) as

```
An estimate of the statistical variance of the RTP data packet
interarrival time, measured in timestamp units and expressed as an
unsigned integer.  The interarrival jitter J is defined to be the
mean deviation (smoothed absolute value) of the difference D in
packet spacing at the receiver compared to the sender for a pair
of packets.
```

They also provide an example implementation in [A.8](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3550#appendix-A.8).

If you want to see an implementation you look at Pion WebRTC's implementation [here](https://github.com/pion/interceptor/blob/master/pkg/report/receiver_stream.go#L74) I don't know where it is in Google's implementation.

Comment: I wasn't looking for the definition of jitter, more specifically what the jitter value in getStats actually refers to (in the webRtc C++ library).  This *is* an implementation, I thought anyway.

Comment: Sorry I don’t understand. This is the exactly what the jitter is in GetStats. It is the value pulled from the ReceptionReport. But the RFC isn’t a general definition of jitter, but a specific formula for RTP.

Comment: So from that I take it that the value "jitter" receievd in the "remote-inbound-rtp" json section equivalent to J (interarrival jitter) ? and more importantly this is continuously updated and the latest received is the most accurate for the call?   I was worried it was essentially only applicable somehow to the *last* pair of packets ...

Comment: That is correct! It is constantly updated, not just the last packet RTT.

Comment: Ok that's what I was looking for.  Thanks, I'll mark your question correct.